# Ruby: reference to numeric values

Tags: ruby, pass-by-reference

How can I keep references to numeric values in a Hash in Ruby? Say I have

```
h={"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
c=h["a"]
```

When I do

```
c+=1
```

I get:

```
irb(main):079:0> c+=1
=> 2
```

but

```
irb(main):080:0> h
=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
```

so `h` has not changed. Can I somehow retain refernces to numeric values and modify them outside the hash `h`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are already holding a reference to the numeric value, it's just that the operation you do to it generates a new numeric value instead of changing its own value.

For practicality, we can say that `c` holds a reference to the number `1` (although there's a subtle implementation difference between `Fixnum` and `Bignum`). For `c += 1`, you're effectively doing `c = c + 1` and the `+` operator of the number actually returns a new number. So the variable `c` is assigned with the reference to the new number.

This will be a different case if there's a method that can change the the value of the object itself. For example, on `String`, the `<<` operator changes the value of the object:

```
h = {"a" => "foo"}
b = h["a"]
b << 'bar'
puts b # foobar
puts h # {"a"=>"foobar"}
```

But in your case, it is an `Integer` and there is no way to change the numeric value of it.

Comment: Again, the fact that numbers are immutable is irrelevant here. Rebinding a variable simply will *never ever* mutate an object. Not in Ruby. Not in any other programming language I know of. The *exact same* thing happens with a `String` or an `Array`, even though those are mutable: `h = {"a" => "foo"}; c = h["a"]; c += 'bar'; h`.

Comment: Yes, but I think the point here is about doing something with the number, as asked in the question: "Can I somehow retain references to numeric values and modify them outside the hash `h`?". So I would think if there is something like `c.replace(c + 1)` as in [`String#replace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001144), that would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: @htanata: Thank you for your answer. I get the story with the '+' operator now (and also the general implications (Jörg)). Now, how can I alter a numeric value in a hash without accessing it via the key, e.g. apply a math-transformation to all the hash values?

Comment: @A.M.: Just loop through the hash and assign the new value to the hash. For example `h.each_pair { |key, value| h[key] = value + 1 }`.

Answer (score 0):

The  `c` is its own variable, so changing the value of `c` doesn't change the value of the item in the hash.

To achieve the effect you want, you can make the hash item an array instead:

```
h={"a"=>[1], "b"=>2}
c=h["a"] # c is now a reference to the hash item, an array
c[0]+=1 # modifying the array
h # print the hash
```

(The text after `#` is a comment; I am not sure whether they will be ignored by the Ruby console.)

Comment: They will be; irb ignores comments just like Ruby

Comment: @Peter: Thanks, that's also an interesting option (to package the values in an array first).

Comment: @A.M. actually, Array here is not mandatory. Any mutable object is OK (e. g. `Hash`).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is that there is only ever one '1' (which is why it's a good idea that it be immutable, obviously). It's not like a String where two variables could share a reference to it, and change it under the feet of the other variable, like:

```
a="foo"
b=a
b.clear
a => ""
```

To do what you want, you can use the key:

```
c="a"
h[c]+=1
h=> {"a"=>2, "b"=>2}
```

Or otherwise use a value that can be changed in-place (as suggested above)

Answer (score 0):

The 'c' should be point to the Key, Numeric is immutable, so you can't change the Numeric value. And ruby prefer to use Symbol for key.

```
h = {:a => 1, :b => 2}
c = :a
h[c] = 3
puts h # {:a => 3, :b => 2}
```

If your array value is String, you can:

```
h = {:a => '1', :b => '2'}
c = h[:a]
c.replace '3'
puts h # {:a => '3', :b => '2'}
```

or you can create your a class, make the Numeric c can be change.